# Check whether item is in SAS list

Tags: sas

I have a SAS list. This SAS list is stored in a macro variable. Please assume that I have no table to derive this SAS list.

The SAS list contains names separated by commas. An example of the SAS list macro variable:

```
%LET sas_list = name1,name2,name3;
```

I want to check whether macro-variable “item” is present in the list.

Something like:

```
%IF &item. IN &sas_list. %THEN %DO;
Whatever;
%END;
```

For some reason, I get the error:

```
“A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: name1 IN name1,name2,name3”
```

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `minoperator` and `mindelimiter` system options. These stand for Macro IN Operator and Macro IN Delimiter.

```
options minoperator mindelimiter=',';

%LET sas_list = name1,name2,name3;
%LET item = name1;

%IF &item. IN &sas_list. %THEN %DO;
    %put &item is in &sas_list;
%END;
```

Output:

```
name1 is in name1,name2,name3
```

If you want to find values that are *not* in a list, pass it through `%eval`.

```
options minoperator mindelimiter=',';

%LET sas_list = name1 name2 name3;
%LET item = name4;

%IF %eval(&item. IN &sas_list.) = 0 %THEN %DO;
    %put &item NOT in &sas_list;
%END;
```

Output:

```
name4 is NOT in name1,name2,name3
```

Note that you can also supply these options directly in a macro if you only want `in` to work selectively. For example:

```
%macro foo / minoperator mindelimiter=',';
    ...
%mend;
```

Comment: You can assess the NOT state by parenthesizing the IN operation.  `%IF NOT (&item. IN &sas_list.) %THEN %DO; ...`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use two options here:

1. [`MINOPERATOR`](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p0pbehl7wj5sl4n1ov1ortnehtba.htm), this will allow the use of the IN operator
2. [`MINDELIMITER`](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/n0vc5y2nyi55dvn1agla9j658kwh.htm), this will allow you to set the delimiter

```
%let sas_list = name1,name2,name3;
options minoperator mindelimiter=',';
%Macro want(item);
    %if &item. in &sas_list. %then %put i = 1;
    %else %put i = 0;
%mend;
%want(name1);

i = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `FINDW` funtion to ascertain the presence of an item in a list.

```
%if %sysfunc(FINDW(%upcase(%superq(saslist)), %upcase(&item), %str(,))) %then %do;
...
%end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supporting

```
 %LET sas_list = name1,name2,name3;
```

you can find if `name2` is in the list this way.

```
data test;
    it = findw("&sas_list", 'name2',',');
run;
```

but I assume you want to find it out without using a `data` step, so

```
%let het = %sysfunc(findw(%quote(&sas_list),name2,%quote(,)));
%put NOTE: het is &het;
```

does the job. Note

- you find is not a macro function, so you need `%sysfunc()` to call it in a macro statement
- you have to mask the comma's with `%quote()`. Otherwise they would be considered argument separators.